# Sending money via PayPal anonymously

Tags: money-transfer, paypal

I know PayPal payments are not anonymous (people can see your email and all that) but my question is, if the payment will arrive to the bank account it's related to, will the banking system there (if it's government controlled) will be able to tell which country the payment came from?

Any ideas?  Other payment methods that aren't PayPal could be good too.
I don't want to get a person in trouble by sending them money.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are looking for a way to send some money to someone in a different country in such a way that it is not apparent that the funds came from your home country.  Is that correct?

Comment: That is exactly it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope.

For them the money will come from Paypal, likely in their country. That said, they can easily ask for the information and paypal will give it. You know, money transmitter license etc.

Comment: What about other methods of payment?

Comment: You mean laws do not apply? Here is your best choice: Cryptocurrencies. This at least decouples the sides legally. THAT SAID: you will get into money laundering assupmtions VERY fast.